# What is the purpose of xsc and xss file in VS2010?

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2010, xsd

I am creating a xml file and wanted to add a xml schema file to it. So i added an .xsd file but it contains .xss and .xsc files. Do i need to do anything on those files to get my schema definition right? What is the purpose of them?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Oh..k..finally i got it...

Now that I think about it I think the behavior I am seeing is because of how the file was originally created rather than the XSD itself. If we originally created the file as a dataset (which generates an XSD) then we'll get all the baggage files (.cs, .xsc, .xss).  These files are created because the XSD represents a dataset rather than a pure XML schema file.  If we don't want the schema treated as a dataset then open the XSD file in the text editor and remove the various msprop and msdata attributes applied to the root dataset element.  Then we can delete the subfiles associated with the file and be left with the raw XML XSD.  VS will then treat the file as a regular XSD.

so i opened the xsd file in text editor and changed

```
msdata:IsDataSet="true"  to

 msdata:IsDataSet="false"
```

When i reload the project, the files were no longer there..

But the question still remains - even though we are not using these files, we are able to get the output so are these files just for the sake of designing and not for any other purposes?

Is there any one who have worked with these files ? can any one give one example in which we are treating xsd as dataset ?

Answer (score 5):

the .xss stores details of how tables are placed in the visual 
representation of the dataset.

https://datatypes.net/open-xss-files